# How to update Graph or chart dynamically in android?

Tags: android, charts

***I am using AChartEngine library for graphs***

I am able to create a graph

```
GraphicalView view = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(mContext, mXYDataSet, mXYMultipleRenderer);
```

But when the view has already been created, there is no method that performs adding/removing points on chart inside `GraphicalView` class.

In my project I need to update chart dynamically with new dataset every second. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

In the AChartEngine Demo App you can try the "Embedded line chart Demo" where you can dynamically update a graph. The code this demo uses is the `XYChartBuilder` class and the source for that is included with the AChartEngine, so you will probably find the answer in the source code for that class.